# TypeScript various file extensions explained?

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

In trying to understand **TypeScript** a little more, what are the relations between all of the file extensions?

- TypeScript, `*.ts`
- Definition, `*.d.ts`
- Map, `*.map`
- JavaScript, `*.js`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I initially started entering the question above thinking to myself that someone would come along and help me out. Then I noticed an *"answer your own question"* option and I was inspired by [Jeff Atwood's encouraging blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) - so I decided I should attempt to answer my own question. I had to do some research but now I have the understanding I was originally looking for.

---

- TypeScript, `*.ts`

A typed superset of **JavaScript** that "compiles" to plain **JavaScript**. These files have the potential to utilize *type-safety* and *strongly-typed* syntax, with **IDE** intellisense.

- Definition, `*.d.ts`

A `*.d.ts` file is used to provide **TypeScript** type information about an *API* that's written in **JavaScript**. Type definition files contain the defining types for all of the public **APIs** within a corresponding `.js`, for example - `JQuery` has `jQuery.js` without the `jQuery.d.ts` a **TypeScript** file consuming `jQuery` wouldn't know about its types, therefore intellisense is gone.

- Map, `*.map`

A `.map` file is a source map file that let tools "map" between the emitted **JavaScript** code and the **TypeScript** source files that created it. This concept has been around since **CoffeeScript**.

- JavaScript, `*.js`

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Introduction):

> JavaScript is a cross-platform, object-oriented scripting language. It is a small and lightweight language. Inside a host environment (for example, a web browser), JavaScript can be connected to the objects of its environment to provide programmatic control over them.

The relationship between a `.ts` file and a `.js` file is that a **TypeScript** file compiles down to a **JavaScript** file.

Comment: *.ts is also used for transport stream. I wish they would've chosen something else so I wouldn't need to 
right click -> Open with
(spoken by a streamer)

Comment: Ah, hah. So that's why Groove initially wanted to gobble up my .ts files... Interesting.

Comment: Small unimportant nit, but the more accurate word for translating between two high level languages is "transpile", while "compile" usually refers to translation into a low level machine or byte code. That said its not an important distinction and calling JavaScript a high level language is a questionable statement

Comment: I choose "compile" as it is most accurate when referring translating between TypeScript and JavaScript. I do see your point though, and I've heard it argued this way before... The thing to consider is the target, if you're going from TypeScript and you need to be compatible with ES3 for example, there is no way that should be considered "transpiled", since the code is completely unrecognizable in its JS form - it might as well be byte code, since no dev is writing it that way. 